# Limiting number of bar plotly without slice dataframe

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart, plotly-dash

Is there possibilit to limit number of bar in graphic without slice dataframe?

Here my graph with a lot of bars. However I would like to show only 10 bars? Is there a attribute in plotly layout or figure that I can set strait foward?

[image]

Comment: Axes have a range property. So you could probably do it by limiting that range. But I recommend just filtering your dataframe before you pass it to plotly, makes more sense and is probably easier.